# Why is netapi obsolete

Tags: windows, exploit

Why is the ms08_067_netapi exploit obsolete? 
Are there alternatives to this exploit that can help me inject payloads to more recent version of windows?

Comment: it's obsolete because it is relevant to an obsolete OS

Comment: It's obsolete, but still shows up on penetrations far too often

Comment: @schroeder That's debatable. The bulletin also applies to Server 2008 (though not R2), which is still supported. Even if all affected operating systems are no longer under support from Microsoft, it's not unlikely that some organizations would still have them in production use.

Comment: Who's saying it's obsolete? Why not ask them, or see if they've provided references you can check directly?

Comment: Answered the issues for MS08-067, but still voting to close as the question currently posed is ill-defined. Strictly, we can't properly answer "why is x obsolete" unless we know your criteria for judging something to be "obsolete" - thus, this question would generally come down to one of opinion alone. We also cannot (and it's worth noting that none of the 3 answerers, or the 3 commenters - myself included in both - have tried) even begin to address your question of alternative exploits because that's just far too broad and also quite time-sensitive.

Comment: @Iszi you are correct about 2008, I was making the call that non-R2 2008 installs would be considered obsolete (I haven't seen any in a long, long time).

Comment: @schroeder Like Vista and the others, they're out there. Just not a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, MS08-067 (disclosed in 2008) took advantage of a flaw in the way RPC requests were handled (parsed) within the NetAPI32.dll. That code has since been updated with a patch to correct the vulnerability -hence it is obsolete. In terms of application, the vulnerability applied to:

- Windows XP  - **END OF LIFE**
- Windows Vista - **END OF LIFE**
- Windows 2000 - **END OF LIFE**
- Windows 2003 - **END OF LIFE**
- Windows 2008

For a long time, it has been regarded as one of the [most popular exploits](https://community.rapid7.com/community/infosec/blog/2014/02/03/new-ms08-067) available. Reason? It was ubiquitous in the *days of old*. While **most** systems have indeed been patched or updated, this is not true of **all** systems and even last week on a vulnerability scan for a client, I found MS08-067 in their environment. Many legacy systems exist out there and can't be patched for one reason or another (usually worrisome admins). Also consider that other countries around the world are not nearly as update-to-date as the US and many international systems are still vulnerable to this (and other) *one-click exploits*. Point being that MS08-067 is far from irrelevant.

**On Hacking Newer Systems**

It's hard to recommend *one ring to rule them all*, so if you are new to pentesting, consider using a vulnerability scanner to help you identify issues / weaknesses on the system you are targeting. A good scanner will usually point you in the right direction if it finds anything.

Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 1):

As with many things in security, the answer is: ***It depends.***

---

### Attacker/Auditor's Perspective:

All but one of the operating system families affected by MS08-067 are past their end of life. Since Microsoft is no longer providing any support for these platforms, ***most*** of the world has moved away from them and on to newer ones that are not affected by the same vulnerability.

Server 2008 is also affected, and is still under support from Microsoft for nearly four more years. However, ***most*** enterprise systems will have upgraded to at least Server 2008 R2 by now.

The key word here is ***most***. While the large majority of the world has moved on, there will be smaller organizations - and even some large ones - who are slower to adapt. Survey enough of them, and you can be guaranteed to find at least a few installations of *every* platform that's affected by MS08-067.

So, for an attacker/auditor, the question of whether MS08-067 is obsolete boils down to whether or not the organization you're targeting has one or more systems with one of the following platforms on the network:

- Windows 2000
- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008 (not R2)

---

### System Administrator's Perspective:

To the people responsible for maintaining information systems, the answer is still dependent upon which Operating Systems they are using. However, the list is slightly different.

For System Administrators, it's actually more likely that MS08-067 is obsolete than it is for attackers/auditors. But it's important to know why.

Of course, if you're not using an affected OS (listed above) then you don't have to worry about MS08-067 at all. If you are using an affected OS, then the patch may still be obsolete to you because it's been superseded.

In April of 2012, Microsoft posted MS12-054. This re-addressed the vulnerability from MS08-067, thereby rendering the older bulletin "obsolete", and also fixed issues in other operating systems that were still supported by Microsoft at the time.

The only platform affected by MS08-067, which *was not* supported by Microsoft at the time MS12-054 was released, is Windows 2000. So, if you're an Administrator of systems running one of the following operating systems...

- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2008 R2

...then MS08-067 *is* obsolete, *and* you should make sure that you have patches specified in MS12-054 installed instead.

---

### TL;DR:

From an "offensive" standpoint, a security bulletin is only truly obsolete if it will never apply to any system that you will be targeting. That said, MS08-067 is indeed more obsolete than most since most of the world has retired the platforms affected by it.

From a "defensive" standpoint, a security bulletin is only obsolete if you do not manage systems that will be affected by it *or* there is a superseding bulletin for the affected systems you do manage. In this case, the only affected OS for which MS08-067 *is not* superseded is Windows 2000. All others, where applicable, should get MS12-054.

Answer (score -1):

The exploit is obsolete because the exploit abuses a vulnerability [which was discovered, reported and patched by Microsoft back in 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms08-067.aspx). You are unlikely to find a Windows system which runs for 8 years now without ever running an update.

The bug only applied to Windows XP, 2000, Windows Server 2003 and some configurations of Windows Server 2008 anyway. All these versions are obsolete, so you won't even find many systems which would be vulnerable even when not patched.

Comment: Vista is also affected, and Server 2008 - while very old, and likely to have been replaced/upgraded in most environments - is still supported by Microsoft. There are indeed still some organizations out there running old platforms like this. And it's actually not uncommon to find systems that haven't had an old patch like this applied. For some (hopefully rare few), they've just been running that long without being patched. Others probably got stood up more recently, but again the admin didn't bother to patch. And still others will have just missed the odd patch here and there for some reason.